# Linux Ethernet repeater

Tags: linux, ethernet

Is there a way to configure two Ethernet interfaces in a Linux box to work as an Ethernet *repeater*? I.e. what goes in one interface would immediately go out from the other. I know there is bridging, but I would like an even more direct forwarding of *all traffic*, including the reserved MAC addresses starting from 01:80:C2:00:00:00.

And it would be nice if Wireshark could capture all that data.

Comment: "Internet sharing"? Maybe not...

Comment: Heh - my immediate thought was "Gigabit hub for traffic capture" :-)

Comment: I make managed switches, so mirroring ports with one would indeed be an obvious choice. This is kind of special setup though, and would require special firmware to for example allow forwarding those reserved addresses. Just looking for a different kind of out of the box solution here.

Comment: I spent yestereve a couple of hours browsing the inertwebs for this... looks like the only solution is _in_-the-box. I.e. three RJ45 female connectors and two pieces of Cat6 cable in a soapbox :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next socat feature release is going to add options packet-auxdata and iff-promisc. Option packet-auxdata enables copying also VLAN tags, which are filtered by the Linux kernel unless socat does additional work to get those. Option iff-promisc puts the interface in promiscuous mode so that hardware does not filter frames that are not addressed to the host.

These options are not yet available in the current 1.7.4.4 version.

```
socat INTERFACE:eth0,packet-auxdata,iff-promisc INTERFACE:eth1,packet-auxdata,iff-promisc
```

Answer (score 4):

Linux can be configured to allow forwarding *some* of those addresses, but not all of them.

In particular, you can't enable forwarding of `00`/`01`/`02` (STP and LACP frames). The rest (things like LLDP) can be enabled through `/sys/class/net/br0/bridge/group_fwd_mask`, e.g. setting it to 248 to enable transparent forwarding for everything except the three aforementioned groups.

For full forwarding, you might need to make something in userspace instead – i.e. instead of a bridge, run a process to manually copy frames between two separate interfaces:

```
socat interface:eth0 interface:eth1
```

Alternatively, find an Ethernet switch that supports "L2 protocol tunneling" (at least that's what TP-Link calls the feature).

I think OpenBSD or FreeBSD had a "TPMR bridge" mode that would mostly allow this, though.

Comment: The socat solution seems very simple and straightforward, even though there is the additional userspace copying. I'll definitely test that approach.

Comment: Unfortunately socat is unable to copy full Ethernet frames, as the Linux kernel is already removing VLAN tags from them.

Comment: The next socat feature release will contain interface options packet-auxdata,iff-promisc which enable copying also VLAN tags and set the interface in promiscuous mode.

Comment: @KallePokki, I have voted to reject your edit. This answer is correct for  a particular version/release. So, changing it is wrong. Please post a new reply.

Comment: @RohitGupta Well, to be exact, this answer regarding socat is incorrect since the solution does not work for any version. Created a new answer, though.

Comment: @KallePokki, and I have upvoted it.